# Twitter scrapping methods/ hacks without payting for the api

Tags: web-scraping, twitter

I am a student and i am doing a project where I have to scrap tweets of a specific public account to continue with the project. I cannot afford the steep price of 100$ that twitter has set for its API. the free version does not have a get capability, you can only post. Can you recommend any methods or any tools you know which work with the current scenario of twitter.

I have tried various tools like twscrape, twitter-scraper-selenium or even online automation tools but none of them have lead to any development.